# 2004 honda pilot fuel vent problem...can-not-fill-gas-into-tank

Tags: honda, fuel-system, pilot

I have the same problem and have disconnected and drained the fuel vent line numerous times, only to have the problem return.  Would it be OK to disconnect the vent line from the upper fitting and leave it disconnected. I'm thinking that any fuel potentially vented into the environment would not be any worse than what overflows every time I add fuel in the current state.

Comment: there's liquid fuel in the vent line?

Comment: Yes.  Repeatedly disconnected the vent line and drain the small amount of fuel out of it    This provides a temporary fix.  I was wondering if I could safely leave the vent line disconnected.

Comment: you can as a temporary measure. i doubt a failed vent valve or kinked hose would be the source of the problem though. not with liquid fuel in the line. are you positive it's fuel and not water?

Comment: Definitely fuel.

Answer (score 1):

When this happens the most likely culprit is either a plugged EVAP valve or vapour canister.  It could also be a kinked vent hose.